# Form only submits one input field instead of two

Tags: html, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Django along with Bootstrap and I have a page where there are two inputs and a submit button:

```
   <div class="col-lg-5">
         <form id="search_form" align="right" action="/comparison/" class="form-inline" method ="get" role="form">
       <input id="navPersonSearch" class="input form-control" type="text" name="q1"
        placeholder="Search for Actor/Actress"
             autocomplete="off" >

  </div> <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Compare</button>
   </div> <!-- ./col -->
   <div class="col-lg-5">
       <input id="navPersonSearch2" class="input form-control" type="text" name="q2"
        placeholder="Search for Actor/Actress"
             autocomplete="off" >
  </form> 
  </div> <!-- /.col -->
```

However, when you submit the form, only the first value is submitted. For instance in the first input if you have "Tom" and the second input you have "Bob", it will redirect to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/comparison/?q2=Bob
```

when I want both values to be submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML is invalid.  Move the `<form>` tags to completely contain the opening and closing `<div>`s.  Like this:

```
<form id="search_form" align="right" action="/comparison/" class="form-inline" method ="get" role="form">  
    <div class="col-lg-5">  
        <input id="navPersonSearch" class="input form-control" type="text" name="q1"
               placeholder="Search for Actor/Actress" autocomplete="off" >
    </div> <!-- /.col -->
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Compare</button>
     </div> <!-- ./col -->
     <div class="col-lg-5">
         <input id="navPersonSearch2" class="input form-control" type="text" name="q2"
                placeholder="Search for Actor/Actress" autocomplete="off" >
     </div> <!-- /.col -->
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

doing something like

```
<p><strong></p></strong>
```

is bad and cause errors in interpretation of html code
you should move for tag ahead

```
<form id="search_form" align="right" action="/comparison/" class="form-inline" method ="get" role="form">
   <div class="col-lg-5">
       <input id="navPersonSearch" class="input form-control" type="text" name="q1"
        placeholder="Search for Actor/Actress"
             autocomplete="off" >
   </div> <!-- /.col -->
   <div class="col-lg-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Compare</button>
   </div> <!-- ./col -->
   <div class="col-lg-5">
       <input id="navPersonSearch2" class="input form-control" type="text" name="q2"
        placeholder="Search for Actor/Actress"
             autocomplete="off" >
    </div> <!-- /.col -->
  </form>
```